# Синтаксические знаки C++

Tags: c++

Кто-то может написать или скинуть ссылку на табличку с некоторыми синтаксическими знаками C++ ?

Вроде &&, ||. (и, или, и т.д.)

Также можно подробнее о всех этих

n, %d и т. д.

Просто С++ изучаю, как второй язык и не могу найти применения этих знаков.

Comment: Берите хороший учебник и последовательно его читайте. Тогда подобных вопросов не будет возникать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [Операторы в C++](http://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/).
2. Форматированный [ввод](http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/) и [вывод](http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/).

---

По поводу ввода-вывода в C++: рекомендую ознакомиться с таким понятием, как [потоки ввода-вывода](http://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/) ([то же самое для файлов](http://cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/)).

Comment: http://www.ifi.uzh.ch/vmml/teaching/lectuces/systems-hs11/C_plus_plusRef_Card.pdf

Comment: @alexlz интересная таблица, но некоторые примеры неудачны, и не все темы описаны (например, виртуальное наследование)